# Searching for a word in a text file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a small txt file containing three lines of text. I'm trying to create a programme in C# that gets a word from a user and searches for that word in the txt file. If the word is found, I'm wanting to record and display what lines of the txt file the word was found on.  The variable int position records if the word is found or not, but I can't work out how to record what lines the word is found on. How would I do this? Here is my code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.Write("please enter a file to search for");
        string fileResponse = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("please enter a word to search for in the file");
        string wordResponse = Console.ReadLine();
        StreamReader myfile = File.OpenText(fileResponse);
        string line = myfile.ReadLine();
        int position = line.IndexOf(wordResponse);
        int count = 0; //counts the number of times wordResponse is found.
        int lineNunmber = 0;

            while (line != null) {
                if (position != -1) {
                    count++;
                }
                line = myfile.ReadLine();
            }
         if (count == 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("your word was not found!");
         } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Your word was found " + count + " times!" + position);
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: Your algorithm specifically counts the number of lines it is found on, NOT the number of instances.  A word can appear 54 times on a single line and only found once using the method IndexOf() .  Also you need to update the position every time you traverse the while loop

Comment: Hi Steve, so the int position variable counts the number of lines the word is found on?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to print the matching lines and the associate line number. Currently you only remember the number of times you matched. The position you print at the end is wrong, and most likely -1 (unless your last match is on the last line). If you don't need to do anything else with the matches, easiest way would be to print when you find it.

(Also, you're not closing the file you're opening)

```
using (StreamReader myFile = File.OpenText(fileResponse))
{
    int count = 0; //counts the number of times wordResponse is found.
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while(!myFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = myFile.ReadLine();
        lineNumber++;
        int position = line.IndexOf(wordResponse);
        if (position != -1) {
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("Match #{0} {1}:{2}", count, lineNumber, line)  
        }
}

if (count == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("your word was not found!");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Your word was found " + count + " times!");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

edit:spelling

Comment: Hi Fai, I have declared using System.IO; at the top of my application. Where would I place put                                                                           using (StreamReader myfile = File.OpenText(fileResponse))? If I put it at the top of the file then myfile doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: my code starts at your StreamReader myFile line, and replaces the rest. 'using' is a C# construct that will close the file when you exit the closing brace.

Comment: Ok if I use your code starting from my myFile line, then it says that myFile and lineNumber do not exist in the current context.

Comment: lineNumber was spelled lineNunmber and myFile was spelled myfile. Note that c# is case sensitive. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework task so I'm only going to give you some hints:

1. Every time you call "myfile.ReadLine()", you have moved to the next line of the file. You might want to track how many lines you have read.
2. To record a list of values, you can use a `List<Type>` variable.

   Example:

   ```
   // Create the list
   List<int> myListOfIntegers = new List<int>();

   // Add some values
   myListOfIntegers.Add(2);
   myListOfIntegers.Add(5);
   myListOfIntegers.Add(3);

   // Iterate through the list
   foreach(int item in myListOfIntegers)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Item Value: " + item);
   }
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Item Value: 2
   Item Value: 5
   Item Value: 3
   ```

Comment: Add should be capitalized

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks for the tips here. When I put lineNumber in my while loop to track the lines, it says that lineNumber doesn't exist in the current context. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: @Gabe You've misspelt `lineNumber` in your declaration. You've declared it as `lineNunmber`. Note the extra 'n' in the middle of the word

Comment: Thanks Grant, just clicked right before I saw your comment. I've noticed that count is always three if the word is found. This matches the number of lines in the txt file. Is this because it's not recording the instances of when the word was found?

Comment: @Gabe Found the issue, you are only searching the first line for the text. The `position = line.IndexOf(wordResponse);` line is what searches the current line for your text. You'll have to run that for every line (before you do the `if (position != -1)` check)

Comment: @Grant,do you mean that                                                                     position = line.IndexOf(wordResponse);                                                           has to go immediately above if (position != -1)? within the while loop?

Comment: @Gabe, Yep. That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Grant. Am i right in thinking that string line = myfile.ReadLine(); is what reads through the file, line by line? Does this increment automatically without any counter? I understand what I'm trying to do. 1) search through the file, line by line. 2) search for desired word in each line. 3) Keep track of line number 4) If the word is found, record the line number.                      I'm still learning how to implement this into programming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85371/discussion-between-grant-peters-and-gabe).